# Combining ST_Touches and ST_Buffer

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm looking for a PostGIS/Postgres query thats a bit tricky.

I want to find all polygons within a specified radius and all neighboring polygons to the polygon where I have my coordinates

```
SELECT * 
FROM polygons_wgs84 
WHERE 
ST_Intersects(geom,
 ST_Transform(
     ST_Buffer(
       ST_Transform(
         ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.116447, 60.548203), 4326), 
       3857), 
     1000), 
 4326)
)
```

And the polygons that `ST_Touches` the polygon that contains this point.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
-- s1: the point
WITH s1 AS (SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.116447, 60.548203), 4326) AS geom),
-- s2: polygon(s) where the point is in
s2 AS (SELECT
    p.geom FROM s1, polygons_wgs84 p WHERE ST_Intersects(p.geom, s1.geom)),
-- s3: polygon(s) which touch s2
s3 AS (SELECT
    p.geom FROM s2, polygons_wgs84 p WHERE ST_Touches(p.geom, s2.geom)),
-- s4: polygon(s) within a radius of about 492 m from the point (this will also contain s2)
s4 AS (SELECT
    p.geom
    FROM s1, polygons_wgs84 p
    WHERE ST_Intersects(p.geom, ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(s1.geom, 3857), 1000), 4326))
SELECT geom FROM s3
    UNION
SELECT geom FROM s4;
```

I would recommend to reproject your polygon layer and the expression in s1 to UTM 32N for South Norway to have distances in meters. Then you could replace s4 by the more performant

```
-- s4: polygon(s) within a radius of about 1000 m from the point (this will also contain s2)
s4 AS (SELECT
    p.geom
    FROM s1, polygons_wgs84 p
    WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, s1.geom, 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM polygons_wgs84, (SELECT * FROM polygons_wgs84 where ST_Intersects(geom, ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.116447, 60.548203), 4326), 3857), 1000), 4326))) sub WHERE ST_Touches(sub.geom, polygons_wgs84.geom);
```